# show that $xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\le 27$

Tags: inequality, substitution, uvw

> Let $\{x,y,z\}\subset[0,+\infty)$,and $x+y+z=6$. Show that:
>   $$xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\le 27$$

I tried AM -GM  but without success.
$$xyz\le\left(\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3=8$$
maybe $$(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\le \dfrac{27}{8}$$ it doesn't always  true。

Comment: Are you sure it is $x - z$ and not $z - x$ ?

Comment: @DanielV,It's $x-z$ not $z-x$

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda, so it's not $(z-x)$

Comment: AM-GM inequality holds for nonnegative numbers. If $x \geq y \geq z$ then $x-y,x-z,y-z \geq 0$. If $x-y,y-z > 0$ then $z-x < 0$.

Comment: (1) It seems to be possible to reach 27 with values $x \approx 3.878963$ and $y \approx 1.654179$ and $z \approx 0.4668588$.  Also (2) AM-GM only achieves equality when the sums and products are equal (that is, $\frac{a + b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$ but $\frac{a + b}{2} = \sqrt{ab}$ only when $a=b$).  
$$ $$
So if you wish to apply AM-GM on terms $a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \dots$ then you are going to have to pick the $a$ terms such that they are all equal when $x,y,z$  have the values given in (1), because it is possible to reach the value of 27 nothing less will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** 2019/10/05

(add the proof of $a = b = c = 1$ and $ABC(A-B)(A-C)(B-C) = 27$)

$\phantom{2}$

Note that $xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$ is cyclic. WLOG, assume that $z = \min(x, y, z)$.

We only need to prove the case when $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z) > 0$. In other words, we only need to prove the case when $x > y > z$.

Let 
$$A = 2 + 2\cos \frac{\pi}{9}, \quad B = 2 - 2\cos \frac{4\pi}{9}, \quad C = 2 - 2\cos \frac{2\pi}{9}.$$
Clearly $A > B > C > 0$. Using AM-GM, we have
\begin{align}
&xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\\
=\ & \frac{x}{A}\, \frac{y}{B}\, \frac{z}{C}\, \frac{x-y}{A-B}\, \frac{x-z}{A-C}\, \frac{y-z}{B-C}
\cdot ABC(A-B)(A-C)(B-C)\\
\le\ & \frac{1}{6^6}\Big(\frac{x}{A}+ \frac{y}{B}+ \frac{z}{C}+ \frac{x-y}{A-B}+ \frac{x-z}{A-C}+ \frac{y-z}{B-C}\Big)^6
\cdot ABC(A-B)(A-C)(B-C) \\
=\ & \frac{1}{6^6}(ax + by + cz)^6
\cdot ABC(A-B)(A-C)(B-C)
\end{align}
where $$a = \frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{A-B} + \frac{1}{A-C}, \quad b = \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{A-B} + \frac{1}{B-C}, \quad
c = \frac{1}{C} - \frac{1}{A-C} - \frac{1}{B-C}.$$
Let $t = \cos \frac{\pi}{9}$.
Using the identities $\cos 2y = 2\cos^2 y - 1$ and $\cos 4y = 2(\cos 2y)^2 - 1 = 2(2\cos^2 y - 1)^2 - 1 = 8\cos^4 y - 8\cos^2 y + 1$,
we have $A = 2 + 2t, \ B = -16t^4 + 16t^2$ and $C = -4t^2 + 4$.

On the other hand, using the identity $\cos 3y = 4\cos^3 y - 3\cos y$,
we let $y = \frac{\pi}{9}$ to get $8t^3 - 6t - 1 = 0$.

We have
\begin{align}
&ABC(A-B)(A-C)(B-C) - 27 = -(8 t^3-6 t-1)\\
 &\quad \times \left(16384 t^{14}+24576 t^{13}-57344 t^{12}-90112 t^{11}+79872 t^{10}+128512 t^9-59136 t^8 \right.\\
&\quad \left. -89472 t^7+27008 t^6+30976 t^5-7824 t^4-4624 t^3+1076 t^2+162 t-27\right)\\
&= 0.
\end{align}
We also have
\begin{align}
a - 1 &= -\frac{8t^3-6t-1}{2(1+t)(4t^2-2t-1)} = 0, \\
b -1 &= -\frac{(8t^3-6t-1)(32t^5-16t^4-24t^3+12t^2+4t-1)}{16(t-1)(2t+1)(-1+2t)(1+t)(4t^2-2t-1)t^2} = 0, \\
c -1 &= -\frac{t(8t^3-6t-1)}{2(t-1)(2t+1)(-1+2t)(1+t)} = 0.
\end{align}
Thus, we have $a = b = c = 1$ and $ABC(A-B)(A-C)(B-C) = 27$. We are done.

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\geq0$.

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, $xyz=w^3$ and $u=tw$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$(x+y+z)^6\geq1728xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$$ or
$$27u^6\geq64w^3(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$$ or
$$729u^{12}\geq4096w^6(x-y)^2(x-z)^2(y-z)^2$$ or 
$$27u^{12}\geq4096w^6(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ or $f(v^2)\geq0$, where
$$f(v^2)=27u^{12}-4096w^6(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6).$$ 
But $f'(v^2)=24576w^6(2v^4-u^2v^2-uw^3)$, which says that $(v^2)_{min}=\frac{u^2+\sqrt{u^4+8uw^3}}{4}$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that $$f\left(\frac{u^2+\sqrt{u^4+8uw^3}}{4}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$27t^{12}\geq4096\left(3t^2\left(\tfrac{t^2+\sqrt{t^4+8t}}{4}\right)^2-4\left(\tfrac{t^2+\sqrt{t^4+8t}}{4}\right)^3-4t^3+6t\left(\tfrac{t^2+\sqrt{t^4+8t}}{4}\right)-1\right)$$ or
$$(t^3+8)\left(27t^9-216t^6+1216t^3+512-512\sqrt{t^3(t^3+8)}\right)\geq0.$$
Let $t^3=a$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$27a^3-216a^2+1216a+512\geq512\sqrt{a(a+8)}$$ or
$$(3a-8)^2(81a^4-864a^3+7296a^2-10240a+4096)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Nice,Have nice methods? it is said can use AM-GM inequality to solve it

Comment: @wightahtl I'll try to find it.