# $ a,b,c,d\ge0, a+b+c+d=6 $, show that $ |(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(b-d)(a-d)(c-d)|\le27 $

Tags: inequality

Given that $ a,b,c,d\ge0, a+b+c+d=6 $, how to show that $$ |(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(b-d)(a-d)(c-d)|\le27. $$

Sorry for the lack of my own efforts. Here's the update.

Moments ago I have no idea about how to deal with such an issue at all since I cannot even find the optimal value of $a,b,c,d$. I have tried to use the Lagrange Multiplier, but it is difficult for me to solve the equations.

Now my idea (creditted to @dan_fulea) is that we assume $ a\ge b\ge c\ge d \ge 0 $, and set $ x:=a-b, y:=b-c,z:=c-d$, and further assume $ d=0 $(because the goal inequality is only about $x,y,z $ and we can seperate $d$ to the others to make the value of LHS larger), then we have $ 4d+3z+2y+x=3z+2y+x=6 $ and we are to show that $ xyz(x+y)(y+z)(x+y+z)\le27 $.

I wonder how to go on next. Shall I apply $ y={6-3z-x\over2} $ in the LHS?

Comment: Please share with us the own efforts to solve the issue, it is the way it works, potential answerers can give a pointed answer. For instance, let us assume $a\ge b\ge c\ge d$. Can we do this? Can we further assume $d=0$? Why?!

Comment: @Fanyon I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @dan_fulea Thank you for your guidance. I have updated the issue. Sorry :(

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I have updated the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Before we start, i would like to insert some comments showing why this problem is a "difficult problem", and why we need for it rather *ad-hoc* methods of attack. To give full details of the computations, i must also use computer aid, but i hope that dryly accepting the results is compensated by the obtained insight. As it often happens with inequalities with a possible equality case, a key orientation point is knowing which is the equality case.

In our case it is not easy to find the point $(a^*,b^*,c^*)$ (and $d^*=0$) giving the maximal value $27$. Having the point makes things easy. I know it now, i could have introduced abruptly, then use it with its properties. This may give the solution without showing how to search next time. (Try to rephrase the inequality introducing e.g. $a/a^*$, $b/b^*$, $c/c^*$, $(a-b)/(a^*-b^*)$, et caetera., then in the new variables the equality in the inequality happens at places where all the fractions are equal to $1$.)

So i will give my "sincere" searching path, showing how i found the point. [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code (appended) shows that the equality in 
$$
abc(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)\le 27\ ,\qquad 0\le c\le b\le a\le a+b+c=6\ ,
$$
is taken in the point $P^*(a^*,b^*,c^*)$, with components which are the solutions of the one and the same cubic equation:
$$
X^3-6X^2+9X-3=0\ .
$$
Explicitly, numerically:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^* &\approx 3.87938524157181\dots\ ,\\
b^* &\approx 1.65270364466614\dots\ ,\\
c^* &\approx 0.46791111376204\dots\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And for the symmetric expressions in $a^*, b^*,c^*$ we have values
$$
\begin{aligned}
e_1(a^*,b^*,c^*) &= a^* + b^* + c^* =6\ ,\text{ as given,}\\
e_2(a^*,b^*,c^*) &= a^*b^* + b^*c^* + c^*a^* =9\ ,\\
e_3(a^*,b^*,c^*) &= a^*  b^* c^* =3\ \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
These values are different, so the usual inequalities $(e_1/3)^2\ge (e_2/3)$, and/or $(e_1/3)^3\ge e_3$, and/or $(e_2/3)^3\ge (e_3/1)^2$ (are valid, but) cannot be used in the process of combining inequalities, because they hold with $>$ instead of $\ge$ in the case of equality in the initial inequality.

For this reason, and searching for a straightforward proof, i am constrained to do "that ugly things" (that would possibly not be accepted in an IMO as a solution, without a proof of the Lagrange theorem appended, too, and will gain the wooden price in any competition accepting it as a solution). But unfortunately, we get in this way the "algorithmic" solution, learned in school. Without pain. (For the typist.)

---

Solution.

*Lagrange multipliers.* We consider the function $F(a,b,c;t)=abc(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)-t(a+b+c-6)$. Extremal points for $F(a,b,c;0)$ on the given domain are then either boundary points, or points satisfying the system of algebraic equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0 &= F'_a(a,b,c;t)\ ,\\
0 &= F'_b(a,b,c;t)\ ,\\
0 &= F'_c(a,b,c;t)\ ,\\
0 &= F'_t(a,b,c;t)\ ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
equivalently:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac t{abc(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} &= \frac 1a+\frac1{a-b}+\frac 1{a-c}\ ,\\
\frac t{abc(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} &= \frac 1b-\frac1{a-b}+\frac 1{b-c}\ ,\\
\frac t{abc(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} &= \frac 1c-\frac1{a-c}-\frac 1{b-c}\ ,\\
6 &= a+b+c\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
We eliminate $t$ among the first equations, getting the (symmetric) system of algebraic equations in $a,b,c$:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac 1a+\frac1{a-b}+\frac 1{a-c}
\ &=\ 
\frac 1b+\frac1{b-a}+\frac 1{b-c}
\ =\ 
\frac 1c+\frac1{c-a}+\frac 1{c-b}\ ,
\\[2mm]
a+b+c&=6\ .
\end{split}
$$
(The symmetry leads to the "same algebraic equation" for the extremal $a,b,c$.)
Solving this with bare hands is complicated. Using computer assistance, things are simpler:

```
R.<a,b,c> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
def  h(a,b,c): return 1/a + 1/(a-b) + 1/(a-c)
def eq(a,b,c): return R( (h(a,b,c) - h(b,a,c)) * a*b*(a-b)*(a-c)*(b-c) )
J = R.ideal( [a+b+c-6, eq(a,b,c), eq(b,c,a)] )
J.elimination_ideal([b,c]).gens()[0].factor()
```

and the result is:

```
(a - 3) * a^2 * (a - 6)^2 * (a - 2)^3 * (a^3 - 6*a^2 + 9*a - 3)
```

The above is the result obtained after the elimination of $b,c$ in the three equations. The values $0,2,3,6$ for $a$ are not leading to the absolute maximum. It turns out that the last factor produces the extremal value $a^*$. The other two variables are obtained similarly at the extremal point, let $b^*,c^*$ denote these points, also the last factor has them as roots, because of $a^*+b^*+c^*=6$, and in the domain of interest we have $a^*\ge b^*\ge c^*$. The quantity $a^*b^*c^*$ is $3$, the free coefficient of the common minimal polynomial $P(X)=X^3-6X^2+9X-3$, Vieta. The quantity $\prod(a^*-b^*)^2$ (cyclic product w.r.t. the variables $a^*,b^*,c^*$) is the discriminant of $P$, which is:

```
sage: S.<X> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: (X^3 - 6*X^2 + 9*X - 3).discriminant()
81
```

so $(a^*-b^*)(a^*-c^*)(b^*-c^*)=\sqrt{81}=9$, which leads to the extremal value:
$$
a^*b^*c^*(a^*-b^*)(a^*-c^*)(b^*-c^*)=3\cdot \sqrt{81}=27\ .
$$
$\square$

---

*Further comments:* It may be useful to have an explicit representation of the roots $a^*,b^*,c^*$. Their sum is $6=2+2+2$, so we shift them by two:

```
sage: (X^3 - 6*X^2 + 9*X - 3)(X+2)
X^3 - 3*X - 1
```

and compute instead the roots of the polynomial $X^3-3X-1$. They are of the shape $u+v$, $\zeta u+\zeta^2 v$,  $\zeta^2 u+\zeta v$, where $\zeta=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is a primitive root or order three of the unit, and the two Vieta relations give:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &= (u+v)(\zeta u+\zeta^2 v)(\zeta^2 u+\zeta v)
\\
&=(u+v)(u+\zeta^2 v)(u+\zeta^2 v)
\\
&=
u^3+v^3\ ,
\\
-3 
&= (u+v)\underbrace{(\zeta +\zeta^2)}_{-1}(u+v)
+
( u+\zeta v)(u+\zeta^2 v)
\\
&=-(u+v^2)+(u^2-uv+v^2)
\\
&=-3uv\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This gives the sum $1$, and the product $1$ for the quantities $u^3,v^3$, so they are roots of $T^2-T+1$, so $u^3=-1$ and $u$ is a $9$.th root of $-1$, and $v$ is the conjugated value (because uf $uv=1$). The choice $u=\exp\frac{i\pi}9$ leads to $v=\exp-\frac{i\pi}9$, and we obtain the root $u+v=u+\bar u=2\cos\frac{\pi}9$.
And indeed, the computer confirms:

```
sage: (2*cos(pi/9)).minpoly()
x^3 - 3*x - 1
sage: (2+2*cos(pi/9)).minpoly()
x^3 - 6*x^2 + 9*x - 3

sage: (2+2*cos(pi/9)).n()
3.87938524157182
sage: (2+2*cos(5*pi/9)).n()
1.65270364466614
sage: (2+2*cos(7*pi/9)).n()
0.467911113762044
```

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq d,$ $a=x+d$, $b=y+d$ and $c=z+d$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negatives and we need to prove that:
$$xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\leq27\left(\frac{x+y+z+4d}{6}\right)^6,$$ for which it's enough to prove that:
$$xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\leq27\left(\frac{x+y+z}{6}\right)^6$$ or
$$1728xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\leq(x+y+z)^6$$ and see here:

[show that $xyz(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\le 27$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373109)